# Disable a href link of a selected row

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to use jquery to disable a link in a selected row.  My code is below I was able to disable two other elements but the link for some reason I cant disable the link it looks disabled but I can still click on it and also it only disables the link in the first row I wanted to only disable the selected row link.

Jquery

```
function groupVerificationHandler(){
$('#labelNbrFromSummary').val(labelNbrs);
$('#loadDateFromSummary').val(loadDates);
$('#typeFromSummary').val(typeFromSummary);

//check if no check box is checked-+

if(labelNbrs == ''){
    alert('You must select at least one Label!');
    return false;
}

//disable the check boxes
$('input[name=summaryCheckbox]:checkbox').each(function(){
    $(this).attr('disabled', true); 
});
//diable select button
$('#groupVerification').attr('disabled', true); 
    //disable the link
   $('#label').attr('disabled', true);  

$('#verification').load('/analysis/loadVerification',  
$('#formForSummary').serialize());

//  $('#verification').load(url, function(){});
$('#verification').show();
}
```

Form

```
<th class="cb"><input type="button" id="groupVerification" name="selectCheckBox" value="Select">                    
            </th>
<td  id="label" bgcolor='<c:out value="${summary.color}"></c:out>'><a 
                href="/analysis/loadAnalysisDetail?labelNbr=${summary.labelNbr}&loadDate=${summary.loadDate}"><c:out
                        value="${summary.labelNbr}" /> </a>

<td align='center' bgcolor='<c:out value="${summary.color}"></c:out>'>
                <input name='summaryCheckbox' type="checkbox" class="cbx" 
                       value='<c:out value="${summary.labelNbr}"></c:out>,<c:out value="${summary.loadDate}"></c:out>,<c:out value="${summary.eventInd}"></c:out>'>
```

enable Jquery:

```
function enableSelectHandler(){
var message = "You have chosen to cancel this update and will be returned to the summary screen.  \n\nDo you want to continue?";
var answer = confirm(message);
if(answer){
    $('#verification').hide();
    //disable the check boxes
    $('input[name=summaryCheckbox]:checkbox').each(function(){
        $(this).attr('disabled', false);        
    });
    //diable select button
    $('#groupVerification').attr('disabled', false);
            // enable the link
            $('#label').attr('disabled', false);

    //need to check if it is the first load for summary
    if($('#labelNbrFromSummary').val() != '') //Not first time
        labelNbrs = $('#labelNbrFromSummary').val();
    //alert(labelNbrs);
    if($('#loadDateFromSummary').val() != '')
        loadDates = $('#loadDateFromSummary').val();
    //alert(loadDates);
    if($('#typeFromSummary').val() != '')
        typeFromSummary = $('#typeFromSummary').val();
    //alert(typeFromSummary);
}else{
    return false;
}   
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change the href of the link. Setting the outer `td` to be disabled won't do anything. Assuming you don't want to re-enable some other time:

```
$('#label').find('a').attr('href', 'javascript:;');
```

If you DO want to re-enable at some other point:

```
var link = $('#label').find('a').first();
var oldHref = link.attr('href');
link.data('oldHref', oldHref).attr('href', 'javascript:;');
```

And then to re-enable later:

```
var link = $('#label').find('a').first();
var oldHref = link.data('oldHref');
link.attr('href', oldHref);
```

Comment: Thank.. I do need to re-anable the link based on the condition Ive edited my post to reflect the enable jquery function.

Comment: @Fahad: I added a way to do that. If you're using IE9 and later, I'd recommend PSL's solution below.

Comment: I have another question I know initially I said that I only wanted the selected row links to be disabled. However, If I was to disable the the entire column which contains links how would I do that. I tried adding the class to my td element instead id ID but for some reason its still only disabling the links in selected row.

Answer (score 2):

Have you try to use:

```
 $(this).attr('href', '#');
```

OR,

```
 $(this).removeAttr('href');
```

based on Condition ?

Answer (score 2):

You don't want to change the attributes like `href` or anything just use css.

[See Doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/pointer-events) for reference and support, this is not supported in *IE at all for non svg elements* though.

look for `pointer-events: none;` this will disable any pointer events in the anchor tag.

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/z5VtM/)

```
$('#label a').addClass('disabled'); //Add the class when you need to disable and remove it when you want to re-enable.

a.disabled {
  opacity: 0.5;
  pointer-events: none;
  cursor: default;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! But unfortunately my users are all using IE 8

Comment: @Fahad yeah i know... Otherwise would have been an easy solution without playing with attributes and values...

Comment: @PSL: Can't really blame them too much on this one, though, it's not officially part of CSS3 for non-svg elements.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of modifying the link element, how about just catching the click event?

```
$('#label a').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();// Disable the default action of following the link
});
```

If you need to determine if the link is disabled or not, you can use `e.isDefaultPrevented()`

At any point you decided to enable the link again, you can simply remove the event catch:

```
$('#label a').unbind('click');
```

DEMO:
http://jsfiddle.net/d99wF/2/

Comment: If you were to do this, you'd want to put a namespace around that click event, in case there's other click events you don't want to unbind. So you could do `$(#label a').bind('click.disable', function(e){...}` and then `$('#label a').unbind('click.disable');`